# Is it possible to combine active record query with postgreSQL raw query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to combine active record query with postgreSQL raw query ?

Czce.where("time > ? ", "2014-02-09".to_datetime).raw_query

```
  def self.raw_query
    raw_q = 'SELECT cast(ticktime as timestamp(1)) AS ticktime
              ,max(bid_price) as price, max(bid_volume) as volume
              From  czces
              Group BY 1
              ORDER BY 1
              limit 1000;'
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(raw_q)
  end
```

If I do this with `find_by_sql`, the result from database is missing many columns.

And the conditional  `.where("ticktime > ? ", "2014-02-09".to_datetime)` still not works

Here's the query expression `Czce.where("ticktime > ? ", "2014-02-09".to_datetime).find_by_sql(raw_q)`

```
[998] #<Czce:0x007fc881443080> {
          :id => nil,
    :ticktime => Fri, 07 Feb 2014 01:16:41 UTC +00:00
},
[999] #<Czce:0x007fc881442d38> {
          :id => nil,
    :ticktime => Fri, 07 Feb 2014 01:16:42 UTC +00:00
}
```

But the expected result should contains `price`, `volume`

```
from (pry):3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
[4] pry(main)> result[0]
{
    "ticktime" => "2014-02-28 07:00:00",
       "price" => "7042",
      "volume" => "2"
}
[5] pry(main)> result[1]
{
    "ticktime" => "2014-02-28 06:59:59",
       "price" => "18755",
      "volume" => "525"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

Raw `select_all` queries are done as pure *SQL* sent to the server, and records sent back as raw data.

From the Rails Guide for [`select_all`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) (emphasis mine):

> select_all will retrieve objects from the database using custom *SQL*
>   just like find_by_sql but **will not instantiate them**. Instead, you will
>   get an array of hashes where each hash indicates a record.

You could iterate over the resulting records and do something with those, perhaps store them in your own class and then use that information in subsequent calls via *ActiveRecord*, but you can't actually directly chain the two. If you're going to drop down into raw *SQL* (and certainly there are myriad reasons you may want to do this), you might as well grab everything else you would need in that same context at the same time, in the same raw query.

There's also `find_by_sql`, which will return an array of **instantiated** *ActiveRecord* objects.

From the guide:

> The `find_by_sql` method will return an array of objects even if the
>   underlying query returns just a single record.

And:

> `find_by_sql` provides you with a simple way of making custom calls to
>   the database and retrieving instantiated objects.

However, that's an actual instantiated object, which, while perhaps easier in many respects, since they would be mapped to an instance of the model and not simply a hash, chaining, say, `where` to that is not the same as a chained call to the base model class, as would normally be done.

I would recommend doing everything you can in the *SQL* itself, all server side, and then any further touch-up filtering you want to do can be done client-side in Rails by iterating over the records that are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to not use base connection itself, try expand the standard `rails` `sql` form like:

```
Czces.select("cast(ticktime as timestamp(1)) AS ticktime,max(bid_price) as price, max(bid_volume) as volume")
     .group("1").order("1").limit(1000)
```

but if you just explain a condition, i.e. want do you really wnat to get from a query, we'll try to write a proper sql.